# yii2 is querying from a wrong table name when login

Tags: php, yii2

i have database with table users which contains users usernames and passwords and other info, i successfully connected my yii2 project to the database and was able to fetch some data, but when i try to login using one of the username and password that exist in the table users yiiDebugger gives me this exception:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE ("username"=$1) AND ("status"=$2)
```

the table i have is named users, but in the query it appears to be user. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you renamed table? Check model method tableName()

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }
}
```

Comment: i've done that before posting, still gives the same error. @Alex

Comment: can you show this piece of code where error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$user->findOne(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])
```